# How does one determine he has a learning disability?

Tags: learning, disability

> How does a graduate student determine if he has a learning disability? Are there any signs to look for? At what point is it worth seeking a professional opinion?

Some people, at least, believe there are a significant number of adults who would be identified as having a learning disability if they were children now. Some of these adults are in academia, and have succeeded academically despite their disability, perhaps through developing good coping mechanisms. Never-the-less, it may be that there are other techniques they have not thought of/come across that would benefit them.

What signs might suggest that this is the case, in a context where past academic success is the norm and future academic success is the expectation?

Comment: Ask your M.D. for a screening.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not specific to academia. It **may** be on-topic on [health.se] or [cogsci.se].

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: I don't suppose we could close this one *yet*. This question seems to be an interdisciplinary overlap between the SE sites you've suggested and Academia.SE. It can be part of *Life as a graduate student* and it doesn't lie within the 'don't ask about...' part. The question seems acceptable to me.

Comment: I think this could be made more relevant by focusing on the academic side: how to you identify a learning disability in a *graduate student*, who must be very intelligent and may have developed very good coping mechanisms, but maybe is still being held back from achieving their full potential.

Comment: A screening with a primary care doctor (for example, at the campus student health center) is a good place to start....  The type of specialist who focuses specifically on this is called an **educational psychologist**.  Unfortunately, the testing tools used in that field are generally not available unless you *buy* them from the publisher.  There are some checklists for specific conditions, however.  Here are some useful ones: http://www.tourettesyndrome.ca/showthread.php?7737-Tourette-Symptom-Checklist

Comment: I've tried editing the question to something I think would be more appropriate for this site. I don't mind this being undone if the changes are unwelcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From http://ldaamerica.org/adults-with-learning-disabilities-an-overview/ :

> Positive characteristics of adults with LD may include problem-solving skills, compensatory strategies, persistence, empathy, and outgoing personalities.  Areas of difficulty include: difficulty with reading, writing and/or math; poor memory; difficulty following directions; inability to discriminate between or among letters, numbers, and/or sounds; eye-hand coordination problems; difficulty putting things in the right sequence;
>   disorganization; and/or difficulty adjusting to change.

Determining whether an adult has a Specific Learning Disability (SLD) depends on the type of disability (e.g. Auditory Processing Disorder, Dyscalculia, Dysgraphia, Dyslexia, Language Processing Disorder, Non-Verbal Learning Disabilities, or Visual Perceptual/Visual Motor Deficit).  Each disability will manifest itself differently, and the degree of influence will vary by individual.  In general, you will need a professional to determine whether you have said disability (see http://ldaamerica.org/adult-learning-disability-assessment-process/ ).

Answer (score 1):

Going to a psychologist!! Only a person responsible for mental health and prevention of disorders can diagnose you. 
However, before engaging with a psychologist, a student should compare their academic progress with other graduate students from the same field. Also a student needs to know and detect what concepts are crucial in their area of study, so a psychologist can help assess how well person is capable of extending their knowledge of these topics and learning them in depth.